# How to access/print an NSMutableArray element from one view to another view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have an `NSMutableArray` named `mArray` in `view1` and it stores some strings.
Now I want to access/print/compare these elements in `view2`.
Please guide me.

Comment: Did you solve your problem? Please mark the correct answer to mark this post as answered.

Answer (score 1):

write property synthesize for marray  in view1 class.Then  create view1 object in the view2 and use as view1object.marray

Comment: Hi, I have implemented this but on printing view1object.marray on consol its printing null.

Comment: use nslog(@"the objects are %@",view1.objects);

Comment: ya its allocated correctly and also printing values but in view1,,,, and in view2 its printing null.

Comment: that is mostly happen due to the not allocating properly

Comment: In view1:                                                               for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{   [self.recipiName insertObject:[NSString    stringWithFormat:@"cookingType%d",i+1] atIndex:i];
  NSLog(@"recipiName element %@",recipiName);
}     In view2: NSLog(@"element %@",view2.recipiName);

Comment: in the second view test *justTest=[[test alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
 NSLog(@"the test is %@",justTest.mArray);  in the first view - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code.
  mArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:1];
  for (int i=0;i<6; i++) {
   [mArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"some text %d",i]];
  }
  NSLog(@"the marray is %@",mArray);
    }
    return self;
} sure it ll work i tried

Comment: here u r creating array in - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame method I have created it during parsing,, and parsed data is saving in this array.

Comment: then the problem is before parsing that you are accessing mArray after parsing done you use to access the array.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion:

You could put the array in your Controller class,where they both could access.

It is always better to have sharable data in Controller then views if data has to be shared among views.

Answer (score 0):

`view1.mArray`  should do it.

Pls note to `@synthesize` the `mArray` in `view1`.
To print the array in console

```
NSLog(@"mArray from view 1 is %@",view1.mArray);
```

Comment: Hi, exactly the same thing I have done, but it is in view1, I want to print the array value in view2.

Comment: show some so that we can see whats wrong. I think you have not allocated and populated the mArray

Comment: Put the code in AAAAAAAAA's comment. Please refer from there.

Answer (score 0):

If view2 is presented pushed whatever in view1, then you can pass it down as a property from view1.

If both are on the same level, spawned by a super view controller, own the array in a property of the super controller and pass it down to the views.

You can also implement a singleton and share the model as a single instance, accessed directly in the views.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that your views situated in different `ViewControllers`. There are several kinds:

1. Create a property for your target viewcontroller and set your array after creating `VC` instance.
2. Make `-(id)initWithArray:(NSMutableArray*)array;` method for your viewcontroller
3. Use singleton for your whole project,