# Transfer Value from one View to Another

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to pass variables between views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6716855/best-way-to-pass-variables-between-views)

Is there a way to take info from a IBOutlet TextField and use the information in it in another View? This is what I'm working with so far, but since the settings variable is on a different page, I'm trying to figure out how to make the app retain and transfer the information.

h.

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UITextField *one;
    IBOutlet UITextField *two;
    IBOutlet UILabel *three;
    IBOutlet UILabel *four;
    IBOutlet UITextField *settings;
    IBOutlet UITextField *label1;
    IBOutlet UITextField *label2;

}

-(IBAction)Button;

@end
```

m.

```
@implementation ViewController

int VarOne = 0;
int VarTwo = 0;
int VarThree =0;
int VarFour =0;
int VarSettings =0;
int VarLabel1 =0;
int VarLabel2 =0;

-(IBAction)Button{
    VarOne = ([one.text intValue]);
    VarTwo = ([two.text intValue]);

    VarLabel1 = (VarTwo - (VarTwo * (VarSettings / 100)) - VarOne);
    VarLabel2 = (VarThree / ((100 - VarSettings) / 100 - VarFour));
    three.text = [[NSNumber numberWithInt:VarLabel1] stringValue];
    four.text = [[NSNumber numberWithInt:VarLabel2] stringValue];
}

@end
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! There are a TON of questions about this on here already. First, look up the delegate method. :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714586/how-to-access-print-an-nsmutablearray-element-from-one-view-to-another-view

Answer (score 0):

You can use transfer data to your other view in 3 ways:

1) using key-value observation

2) using NSNotificationCenter to post notifications

3) if your view is a custom view, you can write a method like:

```
myCustomView = [[CustomView alloc] initWithFrame....];

[myCustomView rememberThisValue:myTextField.text];

[self.view addSubview:myCustomView];
```